# Using Javascript/jQuery to modify CSS based on Text Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, api

OK Stackoverflowians, Here's the riddle for the day.

I have a weather sidebar widget on a WordPress site that snags all of its data from the Google Weather API.  I would like to set a gradient from RED to BLUE and then, by the magic of the javascript gods, to look at the value of the temperature.

Higher number = closer to RED
Lower Number = closer to BLUE

Is there anything out there that can do this?  Or would I have to start from scratch?

Comment: I think the question's a bit ambigious, in the sense that it's unclear whether you're trying to change something's color (maybe text) depending on temperature, or do you have a gradient scale from red to blue, and you'd like to place a marker somewhere in the scale to correspond to temperature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could express the color using two dimensions like this:

```
var max_temp = 50, // set maximum expected temperature
min_temp = -10, // set minimum temperature
temp_range = max_temp - min_temp, // calculate range
temp_rating = ((temp - min_temp) / temp_range) * 255 // express value in terms of the range multiplied by 255
red = temp_rating, // more temp = more red
blue = 255 - temp_rating; // more temp = less blue
```

Then your CSS color would become:

```
rgb(red, 0, blue)
```

No idea if it will look nice though ;-)

Comment: I like this version, it's more dynamic.

Comment: ADDED - Only problem I'm running into, is that this snippet of Javascript is running before the Google API xml data is being loaded onto the site, so my VALUE for TEMP is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#temp')​.change(function(){
        if($(this).val() < 47)
            $(this).removeAttr("class").addClass("cold");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("class").addClass("hot");
    })​;
});
```

**CSS**

```
​.hot {background: #f00; color: #fff;}
.cold {background: #00f; color: #fff;}
```

**HTML**

```
​<input type="text" id="temp"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Hope this helps! FYI, the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbL6C/). Alternatively, you can use `.keyup()` function too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cJg84/3/) of an adaptation from a similar implementation I made to generate colours for JavaScript heatmap charts.

You pass in a value, a minimum and a maximum value to define a range, which then interpolates and generates a hex value given the first, last and midpoint colours defined in the script. This goes from red to green, given a range of 0 - 50, but it also handles out-of-range values by providing the most extreme colour. Maybe you can modify this to suit your requirements?